# Where would I find such Mario stage snapshots?

Tags: super-mario-bros

I'm a fan of Mario games. I see people posting such of these snapshots and I love them so much. I can see the whole landscape of the level.

I want to have more of them. My question is how can we get such ones?

**Edit**

Would be lovely if we know how to print such snapshots from the game, e.g. SNES emulation.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several online archives for video games' maps and level screenshots

Try for example [The Video Game Atlas](http://www.vgmaps.com/), it breaks screenshots by platform and game, then lists all levels and their available screenshots. For example [this is a link to the Super Mario Bros. screenshots](http://www.vgmaps.com/Atlas/NES/index.htm#SuperMarioBros), below is the level 1-1 screenshot.
[image: Super Mario Bros. level 1-1 screenshot]

The site itself somewhat lists how those images were captured. "ripped" probably means it came for the game files themselves, possibly by stitching together screenshots from emulators; "originals" were made outside the game.

Comment: I go to your site but really don't know where to catch such snapshots. Would be nice if you may pick some specific link. Thank you.

Comment: I probably didn't completely understand you question. When you asked how can you "get" these maps, I assumed you ask where can you find these maps, not how to create them yourself. While the site I linked gives "pre-made" maps, I'm not sure it gives tutorials on how to make those yourself

Comment: You are an awesome guy @JohnoBoy